# Playframework datagrid template

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I have one question about `design` and basic `implementation` of server side data grid control(something like asp.net GridView).

I have created dummy `DataGrid.scala.html` but I can be written in more sophisticated and functional (with functional programming) way.

```
    @(ID: String, List: Seq[model.admin.Partner.Partner], Columns: Seq[String])(content: Html= Html(""))
@import model.admin.Partner.Partner
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        @for(j <- Columns) {
            <td>@j</td>
        }
        </tr>
    </thead>

    @for(i <- List) {
        <tr> @for(j <- Columns) {
            <td> @code.classes.EntityFactory.getValue[Partner](i, j)</td>
        }
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Basically I have one loop for table headers and second double loop for getting value by Reflection.

```
object EntityFactory {
  def getValue[T](entity: T,fieldName: String)(implicit ev: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]) = {
    entity.getClass.getMethods.find(_.getName == fieldName).get.invoke(entity)
  }
}
```

In my view I use this Datagrid like this:

```
    @DataGrid(ID = "partners", List = Partners, Columns = Seq("ID","Name", "ShortName")){

                    }
```

**What I wish to have**

I want have something like this:

```
@DataGrid(ID = "partners", List = Partners){
                        @LinkColumn(ID = "url", Propety = "ID",Url = controllers.admin.routes.PartnerController.read(""))
                        @LabelColumn(ID = "Name", Property="Name", CssClass="Some")
                        @LabelColumn(ID = "Email",Property="Email", CssClass="Some")
                        @DateDateColumn(ID = "ActiveFrom")
                    }
```

Here I created structure for this

[image]

In some columns I would like to do some trick to inject into `Url` route value from `Property`. Something like that:

```
    @(ID: String,entity: Partner, Property: String, Url: String)
@import model.admin.Partner.Partner
    <div>
        here I want to inject code.classes.EntityFactory.getValue[Partner](entity,"ID")
        into @Url
    </div>
<a href="@Url(code.classes.EntityFactory.getValue[Partner](entity,Property))">klik</a>
```

Thanks for reading and help.

---

### EDIT

After some time I finally found answer by myselve. This code is divided by two areas: `code` and `view`.

**Code**

Here are traits or classes which describe types of column.

```
trait Column {
  val ID: String
  val Label: Option[String]
  val Header: String
  val Property: String
  val AlternateProperty: Option[String]
  val Visible: Boolean
  val Enabled: Boolean
}

object Column {}
case class LinkColumn(ID: String,
                      Label: Option[String] = None,
                      Header: String,
                      Property: String,
                      AlternateProperty: Option[String] = None,
                      Visible: Boolean = true,
                      Enabled: Boolean = true,
                      Url: Any => Call,
                      Type: String = LinkColumnType.Action
                       ) extends Column {}

case class LabelColumn(ID: String,
                       Label: Option[String] = None,
                       Header: String,
                       Property: String,
                       AlternateProperty: Option[String] = None,
                       Visible: Boolean = true,
                       Enabled: Boolean = true) extends Column {}

case class MergedActionColumn(ID: String,
                              Label: Option[String] = None,
                              Header: String,
                              Property: String,
                              AlternateProperty: Option[String] = None,
                              Visible: Boolean = true,
                              Enabled: Boolean = true,
                              Actions: Seq[LinkColumn]) extends Column {}
object LinkColumnType extends Enumeration {
  type Type = Value
  val Link = ""
  val Action = "btn btn-success"
}
```

And some helpers code.

```
object EntityFactory {
  def getField(entity: Any,fieldName: String) = {
    entity.getClass.getMethods.find(_.getName == fieldName).get.invoke(entity)
  }
}
```

**Views**

*DataGrid.scala.html*

```
@(ID: String, List: Seq[Any], CssClass: String = "",
        ShowCreateButton: Boolean = true)(Columns: Seq[Any])(implicit request: play.api.mvc.RequestHeader, lang: play.api.i18n.Lang)
@import code.classes.{EntityFactory => ef}
@import code.views.tags.DataGrid.{LabelColumn, LinkColumn, Column, MergedActionColumn}
@import views.html.tags.controls.DataGrid.{LabelColumn => vLabelColumn, LinkColumn => vLinkColumn}
@import code.views.tags.DataGrid.LinkColumnType
@import code.Ext

    @if(ShowCreateButton){
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="@controllers.admin.routes.PartnerController.create()">
            <i class="icon-zoom-in icon-white"></i>
            @Ext.te("common.add", lang.code)
        </a>
    }
<table class="@CssClass">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        @for(j <- Columns) {
            @j match {
                case s: MergedActionColumn =>{
                       <td>@s.Header</td>
                }
                case s: Column => {
                    <td>@s.Header</td>
                }
                case _ => {}
            }
        }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @for(l <- List) {
        <tr>
        @for(c <- Columns) {
            @c match {
                case s: LabelColumn => {
                    @vLabelColumn(ID = s.ID, Header = s.Header, Property = s.Property,
                        Visible = s.Visible)(entity = l)
                }
                case s: LinkColumn => {
                    @vLinkColumn(ID = s.ID, Label = s.Label, Header = s.Header, Property = s.Property,
                        AlternateProperty = s.AlternateProperty, Visible = s.Visible, Enabled = s.Enabled,
                        Url = s.Url, Type = LinkColumnType.Link
                    )(entity = l)
                }

                case s: MergedActionColumn => {
                   <td> <table> <tr>
                    @for(s <- s.Actions) {
                        @vLinkColumn(ID = s.ID, Label = s.Label, Header = s.Header, Property = s.Property,
                            AlternateProperty = s.AlternateProperty, Visible = s.Visible, Enabled = s.Enabled,
                            Url = s.Url, Type = LinkColumnType.Action, CssClass = "no-border no-bg"
                        )(entity = l)
                    }
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                   </td>
                }
            }
        }
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
```

*LinkColumn.scala.html*

```
@(  ID: String,
    Label: Option[String] = None,
    Header: String,
    Property: String,
    AlternateProperty: Option[String] = None,
    Visible: Boolean = true,
    Enabled: Boolean = true,
    Url: String => Call,
    Type: String = code.views.tags.DataGrid.LinkColumnType.Action,
    CssClass: String = "")(implicit entity: Any)

    @import code.classes.{EntityFactory => ef}

    <td class="@CssClass">
        <a href="@Url(ef.getField(entity, Property).toString)" class="@Type">
            @Label.getOrElse(ef.getField(entity, AlternateProperty getOrElse Property).toString)
        </a>
    </td>
```

*LabelColumn.scala.html*

```
@(ID: String,
        Label: Option[String] = None,
        Header: String,
        Property: String,
        AlternateProperty: Option[String] = None,
        Visible: Boolean = true,
        Enabled: Boolean = true)(implicit entity: Any)
@import code.classes.{EntityFactory => ef}
<td>
    @ef.getField(entity, Property)
</td>
```

*Usage of datagrid:*

```
@DataGrid(ID = "facilities", List = Facilities, CssClass = "table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable",
                    ShowCreateButton = true)(
                    Seq(
                        LabelColumn(ID = "ID", Header = "ID", Property = "ID"),
                        LabelColumn(ID = "Name", Header = "Nazwa", Property = "Name"),
                        MergedActionColumn(ID = "Actions", Header = "Actions", Property = "ID", Actions = Seq(
                            LinkColumn(ID = "Update", Header = "ID", Property = "ID", Url = pfc.update, Label = Some("Update")),
                            LinkColumn(ID = "Delete", Header = "ID", Property = "ID", Url = pc.delete, Label = Some("Delete")),
                            LinkColumn(ID = "Delete", Header = "ID", Property = "ID", Url = pc.read, Label = Some("View")),
                            LinkColumn(ID = "Delete", Header = "ID", Property = "ID", Url = pfc.index, Label = Some("Facilities"))
                        ))
                    )
                )
```

Of course this is only base scaldfolding but it shows how to use playframework views like controls in asp.net or jsf.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check existing form helpers and also (outdated) bootstrap support. Check corresponding `html.scala` files in play sources

It is good example of implementation non trivial components in play.